# Vue.js async component not updating template

Tags: javascript, vue.js, async-await

I have a Vue Component where I do a bunch of async calls, which should then populate my template. However, nothing seems to be getting updated, even though I can see in the console that my data is coming back. I'm pretty new to Vue, so I must be missing something. Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
<template>
  <div id="my_component">
        <div v-bind:class="{ hidden: !isLoading }">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" style="margin:auto;background:#fff;display:block;" width="200px" height="200px" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid">
        <circle cx="50" cy="50" fill="none" stroke="#1ba4de" stroke-width="4" r="15" stroke-dasharray="70.68583470577033 25.561944901923447">
          <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="rotate" repeatCount="indefinite" dur="0.9803921568627451s" values="0 50 50;360 50 50" keyTimes="0;1"></animateTransform>
        </circle>
      </svg>
    </div>

    <div v-bind:class="{ hidden: isLoading }">
      <h1>{{ result.title }}</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>


<script>
export default {
  name: 'MyComponent',
  data () {
    return {
      isLoading: true,
      result: null
    }
  },
  async created () {
    this.result = await myLongRunningAsyncFunction();
    this.isLoading = true;
    console.log(this.result) // Logs result of myLongRunningAsyncFunction()
  }
  methods: {
    myLongRunningAsyncFunction: async function() {
     // Make a bunch of API calls and get some data
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `this.isLoading = false;` in the `created` hook?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of toggle a class you can use `v-if` to hide/show elements. I am not sure what your `hide` class looks like but i guess its something like `display: none` witch is less efficient.

```
<div v-if="!isLoading">
    <h1>{{ result.title }}</h1>
</div>
```

You also need to set `isLoading` to `false`

```
async created () {
    this.result = await myLongRunningAsyncFunction();
    this.isLoading = false;
    console.log(this.result) // Logs result of myLongRunningAsyncFunction()
}
```

Also in your first div, this would look much nicer:

```
 <div v-bind:class="{ hidden: !isLoading }">
```

to this:

```
 <div v-if="isLoading">
```

Comment: Cool, thanks. As an exercise for myself, I tried to go back to first principles and worked out there was actually an issue with my code that was stopping it from working! These are nice suggestions though. I'll set this as the accepted answer :)